# MongoDB crashes when creating Index

Tags: python, mongodb

The Database has 3 Collection loaded with 4 billions records. I've tried to index all at once and
individually. Everytime when the scanning is done the mongodb crashes/stops the service.

[image]

[image]

Im running theese commands in the MongoDB shell to index.

```
use Database
db.collection.createIndex({value: 1})
```

Since inserting with an index is very slow, the index has to be created after the insertion. Error Logs: https://throwbin.io/6dwpow7

Comment: That error is not related to index build process.

Comment: @AliTou So why is it crashing when the scan is done?

Comment: Do you have access to mongodb logs? I think it can clear things for us.

Comment: https://throwbin.io/6dwpow7 Here are the error logs.

Comment: The problem is with `errno:24 Too many open files` part. How do you run your mongodb instance? Is it located on the cloud? If you are using a Linux distribution, can you set `ulimit` parameters for its process? If so, what is the output of `ulimit -n`?

Comment: Add all information to the question instead of comments.

Comment: The mongodb is running on a Hetzner dedicated server to be specific a AX51. Will try the parameter, thanks.

Comment: Its running windows btw.

Comment: You're probably running out of swap space. It's a common problem with mongodb (especially when using mongorestore). Try increasing your swap space.

Comment: That has nothing to do with that. I was running a windows server where the Max. files open has a limit and linux don't.