# Increase Maximum open files per session in Windows Server 2019 | MongoDB Too many open files error

Tags: windows, mongodb

Im trying to index a MongoDB database with a lot of records. Sadly, im getting the "Too many open files" error when MongoDB is done with scanning the database to continue with indexing. As im using windows server 2019, there is no command like "ulimit". I also couldn't find any way to increase the "Maximum open files per session" in windows. Anyone knows how to?

Also in this question is the Error code included: [MongoDB crashes when creating Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876347/mongodb-crashes-when-creating-index)

Kind Regards.

Comment: I know there's a way to do it but can't remember what it is.  But you can't raise the limit arbitrarily, there's a limit on the limit too that might still be too small for you.

Comment: I will probably end up switching to linux... The issue is I have to index the database after insertion, because its too large. If I would index it before the insertion, the insertion would slow down dramatically.

Comment: windows and mongodb are not good friends. you'll be better off running mongo in linux.